# How do I get content of a text cursor in Libreoffice Writer?

Tags: libreoffice, basic, libreoffice-writer

I want to get content of a text cursor in Libreoffice Writer. In this case, the content of the first word in the document.

I tried the code below. The last line in the sub gets me the content of the whole document not of the first word. I do not want that. I want the content / string of the first word.

```
Sub Test4
  Cursor = ThisComponent.Text.createTextCursor()
  Cursor.gotoStart(False)
  Cursor.gotoEndOfWord(True)
  msgbox Cursor.Text.getString()
End Sub
```

Comment: Why `,Text.`? May be `msgbox Cursor.getString()`?

Answer (score 0):

The right answer is this.

```
Sub Test4
  Cursor = ThisComponent.Text.createTextCursor()
  Cursor.gotoStart(False)
  Cursor.gotoEndOfWord(True)
  msgbox Cursor.getString()
End Sub
```